# Верификация полей формы в модальном окне bootstrap vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Есть небольшой vue проект. Использую bootstrap-vue.

По примеру [prevent-closing](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#prevent-closing) пытаюсь сделать модальное окно с формой.

В форме несколько полей (должны быть только цифры, должны быть заполнены все).

**Код:**

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="b-container">
      <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button>

      <b-modal
        id="modal-1"
        hide-footer
        title="Please, enter code:"
        :body-bg-variant="bodyBgVariant"
      >
        <form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
          <div class="pin-num text-center">
            <ul class="pin-num-list">
              <li :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in itemNum">
                <b-form-input :id="item.id" :v-model="item.name" :state="item.nameState" required></b-form-input>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <b-button @click="handleOk" class="mt-4" variant="primary" block>Submit</b-button>
        </form>
      </b-modal>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "AppPin",
  data() {
    return {
      pin: "",
      bodyBgVariant: "light",
      name: "",
      nameState: null,
      submittedNames: [],
      itemNum: [
        { id: "num-1", name: "", nameState: null },
        { id: "num-2", name: "", nameState: null },
        { id: "num-3", name: "", nameState: null },
        { id: "num-3", name: "", nameState: null },
        { id: "num-5", name: "", nameState: null },
        { id: "num-6", name: "", nameState: null }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkFormValidity() {
      console.log(this.itemNum.nameState);
      const valid = this.$refs.form.checkValidity();
      this.itemNum.nameState = valid ? "valid" : "invalid";
      return valid;
    },
    handleOk(bvModalEvt) {
      // Prevent modal from closing
      bvModalEvt.preventDefault();
      // Trigger submit handler
      this.handleSubmit();
    },
    handleSubmit() {
      // Exit when the form isn't valid
      if (!this.checkFormValidity()) {
        return;
      }

      console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAA");

      // Hide the modal manually
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.modal.hide();
      });
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**Вопрос:** Как по примеру реализовать верификацию формы в модальном окне ? Если все заполнено (цифрами) , то "submit" отправляет результат и закрывает окно, если не верифицировано - не отправляется форма и не закрывается окно.

Comment: вся соль вот в этой строчке `const valid = this.$refs.form.checkValidity();` Чтобы это заработало, необходимо в инпуты добавить аттрибут `pattern`, с соответствующей маской

Comment: @Дмытрык, а в примере на бутстрапе просто require. Мне казалось в этом проблема `this.itemNum.nameState` выдает undefined хотя должно быть или vakid или unvalid

Comment: `itemNum` - у Вас массив. Поэтому все верно пишет.  Попробуйте записать так: `this.nameState = valid ? "valid" : "invalid";`

Comment: @Дмытрык, спасибо! Заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать обычную валидацию формы на vue

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    errors:[],
    name:null,
    age:null,
    movie:null
  },
  methods:{
    checkForm:function(e) {
      if(this.name && this.age) return true;
      this.errors = [];
      if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required.");
      if(!this.age) this.errors.push("Age required.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input,select {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form id="app" @submit="checkForm" action="/something" method="post">
  
  <p v-if="errors.length">
    <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name<label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="name">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="age">Age<label>
    <input type="number" name="age" id="age" v-model="age" min="0">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="movie">Favorite Movie<label>
    <select name="movie" id="movie" v-model="movie">
      <option>Star Wars</option>
      <option>Vanilla Sky</option>
      <option>Atomic Blonde</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: при чем тут name age ? Есть 6 полей под цифры которые выводятся циклом (в этом видимо и проблема) и которые нужно проверить на валидацию. Спасибо, но не то! И все же желательно bootstrap-vue

Comment: это валидация формы. Верификация полей формы. Не важно какие компонеты и где форма. Делайте по примеру что я вам показал.